# how do i save score in android studio?

Tags: kotlin

so I'm creating simple tic tac toe game and I want to make it so that if player 1 wins it should show the score up top how many times they have won.

I had few ideas which obviously didn't work. One of them was trying to save score in list and then putting it in edit Text so that it would show up, I don't know if it was a valid idea from the beginning but after I tried the application kept on crashing after 1st game. I'd greatly appreciate the help, thanks in advance.

Comment: I made small progress now it doesn't crash but the counter does not go up above 1

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.